# Why is clicking on a Google search result sending me to a different page than just typing in the same URL?

Tags: google-search

I was trying to track down the website of a local nonprofit, so I typed its name into Google. The first result showed the organization's actual domain name, but the description was spam, and clicking on it brought me to a spammy website.
[image: spammy Google result]

(for reference, the URL for this search is https://www.google.com/search?q=united+neighborhoods+of+santa+clara+county)

My first thought was that the domain had expired and been poached, or some sort of compromise of the organization's web server. But then I found that just typing http://www.unscc.org/ into my browser brings me to the organization's actual website.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: looks like the fake site exploits google adds by acting as a valid site and then injecting redirection key - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR822.png

Comment: @user0 could you elaborate, perhaps into an answer? I'm not sure what I'm supposed to look at in that screenshot.